# OCM Landscape data

Tags: data

What is the source of the OCM Landscape data and where can one obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

OCM = OpenCycleMap?

These tiles are coutesy of Andy Allan, as written on the original openstreetmap.org layer. But he won't give the source code to the public. In low zoom levels, he has taken the satellite pictures of blue marble by NASA, and replaced the sea by a brighter shade of blue.

Answer (score 0):

Homepage:
http://www.thunderforest.com/

Terms and Conditions:
http://www.thunderforest.com/terms/